# git merge results in "fatal: stash failed"

Tags: git

I have a branch A from which I created a branch B. I've done some commits in branch B, and now when I do

`git merge A`

Git gives me the following error:

`fatal: stash failed`

Things I've tried already:

- Check/clear the stash. I'm not actively using stash. I did not have anything on the stash, but did a `git stash clear` anyway.
- `git gc --prune=now`
- `git remote prune origin`
- `git fetch origin --prune`

All without any success.

To be clear:

- This is the only error message shown. There is no other output.
- There are no pending/staged changes. `git status` shows nothing.

Any clue on what's causing this error. More importantly: how to get rid of it?

Comment: What is the output of `git stash list`?

Comment: @infinitezero nothing... As in empty.

Comment: I have a hunch that the shown error message is not the only one. Please post the complete command and its output. Also show the output of `git status`.

Comment: Maybe a permission issue? In bash check with `find .git -not -user "$USER"`

Comment: @j6t the shown error message is the only one. `git status` shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Delete /.git/index.lock file under the .git hidden directory in your repository. This should get stash and merges ultimately back to working.

**Background:**

I have faced the exact same issue, wherein I note that even a simple `git stash` fails to stash any file in the repository.
In my case though, local changes did exist. I had run `git commit` command sometime back and immediately halted it using Ctrl+C to do skip it and do some corrections on top. Then, as `git add` too failed with the error

> fatal: Unable to create 'C:/.../.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
> editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
> terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
> crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
> continue.

I got a clue what is failing it and the related fix , so as suggested I had deleted this file and all operations as `add`, `stash` and `merge` are working right back.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely try this out the next time this happens and will mark this as the solution accordingly.

Comment: Sure, that'd be great. Just in case you'd like to give it a try anytime, I think trying to mimic commit termination (just around waiting for editor to close... prompt) using Ctrl+C key combination or manually using a blank index.lock file under .git/ should allow you to check it out if preferred this way.

Comment: I had the issue again today. Unfortunately there is no `index.lock` inside the `.git` folder in the repository.